# Change the tab stop (\t) size in Spyder's IPython Console

Tags: python, ipython, spyder, escaping, tab-size

For some, it appears that the tab stop size in the IPython Console stop is 4 and not the usual 8.
How do I change it back? I am guessing it has to do with a configuration in Spyder. I looked nearly in all the Preferences options. I could not find a potential solution.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmpPj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find a way to change that, but have a look at `str.expandtabs?`

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) That was removed some months ago because it interfered with [code](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/issues/396) that expected tabs to be tabs (instead of being converted to 8 spaces).

Unfortunately, there's no option to get back the previous behavior either, sorry.